# Get Lync user from phone number

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I'm writing a Managed SIP application that will inspect phone calls, and either allow them or terminate them based on various conditions. I need to know the Lync user that the call is intended for. I'm sure there are cases where a phone number can't map to a user, in that case I'll do something else.

From what I can tell, all I have to work with is the phone number that is being called.

The best solution would be if I could use the Lync API to do this, but if that's not possible, I can look into querying either AD or one of the Lync databases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, you found your answer in the meantime, but to complete the question:

```
Get-CsUser -Filter {LineURI -like $yourNumber}
```